# Why is my Session gone when using RestTemplate to access Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to access a Spring MVC app. That uses a CSRF Token. I do an initial GET to receive the Token. Then add it to my POST with my JSESSIONID. However, during debug the Server app doesn't find my JSESSIONID. And therefore, doesn't authenticate my token, and gives me **403**.

I can't tell but it looks like my GET JSESSIONID doesn't get saved in the server HTTP Session repository.
Is there a way, to validate:

- The session is in the server context?
- Am I sending the correct header data?

Here's my code:

```
public String testLogin() {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = 
    restTemplate.getForEntity(LOGIN_RESOURCE_URL, String.class);

    List<String> cookies = new ArrayList<String>();
    cookies = response.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie");
    String[] firstString = cookies.get(0).split("=|;");
    String jsessionPart = firstString[1];
    String[] secondString = cookies.get(1).split("=|;");

    String tokenPart = secondString[1];

    BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("JSESSIONID", 
    jsessionPart);
    cookie.setDomain(".mydomain.com");
    cookie.setPath("/");
    cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);

    BasicClientCookie cookie2 = new BasicClientCookie("X-XSRF-TOKEN", 
    tokenPart);
    cookie2.setDomain(".mydomain.com");
    cookie2.setPath("/");
    cookieStore.addCookie(cookie2);
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder
            .create()
            .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
            .disableRedirectHandling()
            .build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new 
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

    factory.setHttpClient(client);
    RestTemplate postTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
    HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(body, headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = postTemplate.exchange(loginUserUrl, 
          HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,String.class);
```

To your code sample I added user name and password plus changed the content type. The 403 still happens whether i sent content type or not:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

// if you need to pass form parameters in request with headers.
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
try {
    map.add( URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8"), 
    URLEncoder.encode("userdev", "UTF-8") );

    map.add(URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8"), 
    URLEncoder.encode("devpwd","UTF-8") );
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
}
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<> 
(map, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = 
this.restTemplate(builder).exchange(RESOURCE_URL, HttpMethod.POST, 
requestEntity, String.class);
```

Comment: I have the same results trying the Web Client.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a new `RestTemplate` nor be messing around with cookies yourself. You should instead be configuring the initial `RestTemplate` with the appropriate cookie store and it will handle all the cookies for the URLs itself.

Comment: @m-deinum - do you have an example? I have tried many ways of creating the RestTemplate with no joy so far.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing around with cookies yourself let the framework, Apache HttpClient, handle this for you. Configure the `RestTemplate` to work with a properly configured `HttpClient`.

Something like this should do the trick

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.requestFactory(this::requestFactory)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory() {

    RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.DEFAULT)
            .setExpectContinueEnabled(true)
            .build();

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setDefaultCookieStore(new BasicCookieStore())
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(defaultRequestConfig).build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    return requestFactory;
}
```

This will configure the `RestTemplate` to use a `HttpClient` that stores cookies in a `CookieStore` in between requests. Reuse the configured `RestTemplate` and don't create a new one because you might need it.

Comment: to the code sample I added username and password(see above) and still the same error.

Comment: Then you really must be doing something different, I tested it with a local controller with some session based scope and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @m-deinum Thanks for your time and suggestions. We ended up going a different route.